# Getteing error when trying to log in or create account

Tags: typescript, nativescript, kinvey

i am creating an android application using nativescript, and when i create an account it works and shows up in my kinvey dashboard with my api key and secret key in the app. But when i try to log in with those exact same credentials i get this error in the device logs.

An active user already exists. Please logout the active user before you login.

i have also tried going straight from the code sample not adding anything new and just adding my api and secret key to see if it will allow me to log in and i am getting the exact same error so i know it cant be a problem with my code. please tell me how do i fix this or should i look into using a different database then kinvey. i am using a "good looking login form" code sample from this link

https://market.nativescript.org/?tab=samples&framework=all_frameworks&category=all_samples&_ga=2.9180405.1153787584.1569379856-234073572.1568591732

Answer (score 0):

[From Docs:](https://devcenter.kinvey.com/nativescript/guides/users#signup-1)

> Signup creates a new user in Kinvey. If the username does not already
>   exist in your app backend, a new user will be created. ***The newly
>   created user is automatically logged in as the active user***.
>
> If the user already exists, signup will result in an error.

Either you will have to perform logout to make user login again manually Or let him access the app right away post signup.

Comment: thank you i think i will just use a different code sample for logging in